# Assign result of a method to a variable in ssis script task using c#

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I am using vs 2017 ssdt and would like to assign the result of a method to a variable in script task using C#. I am trying to do this outside of main method. I can read the SSIS variable values in the main method using dts variables but not being able to access it outside of the main method.

```
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
        public void Main()
    {
          //Do something
        }

        private class DifferentClass
        {
         private Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables DtsVariables;
         public string MakeURL()
         {
          return DtsVariables["User::URLBase"].Value.ToString() + "/default.aspx"; // how to assign this value to the below variable
         }

         string urlbase = MakeURL(); //Return results of MakeURL() to the string urlbase
        }
}
```

To explain my problem better if I were to access dts variables outside main() method I get error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase.Dts'.

```
public void Main()
{
string test = Dts.Variables["User::TestString"].Value.ToString(); //This works
}

private class Test
{
string newtest = Dts.Variables["User::TestString"].Value.ToString(); //Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase.Dts'   
}
```